# How to make the install work node-inspector on windows 8.1?

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

My installation of node inspector on win 8.1

```
E:\Totty\Web\example>npm install node-inspector -g
-|-|\|\\\/\|-\|/||/-\\|\/-npm ERR! cb() never called!
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

How to install node-inspector?

Comment: Works on my machine :)

Comment: I made this tutorial for the Mac, but the steps should be the same on Windows. I don't know what's wrong on your machine but maybe following the steps in the video will help you catch some discrepancy. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03qGA-GJXjI

Comment: How about directory from that you work? Is this a project that has package.json with redefined install script for example?

Comment: hangs with the "\" animation...